# usage statistic for bug tracking / task management systems?

Tags: bug-tracking, task-management

Can someone please share a link to bug tracking / task management systems **usage statistics**? 
I want to see which systems are the most popular.

Answer (score 0):

This is a result of Eclipse survey (question 20 in the spreadshhet): http://www.eclipse.org/org/press-release/20110610_survey.php